# How to add all parameters to .txt from form?

Tags: php, forms, file, fwrite, file-handling

My problem is that I want to write all values displayed below into a txt file.

I receive an error when doing so is on the line `fwrite(...)` - It can only except 3 parameters.

Am I doing something wrong? 
Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for your help.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
  $personality = $_POST['personality'];
  $OS = $_POST['OS'];
  $age_min = $_POST['age_min'];
  $age_max = $_POST['age_max'];

  $file = fopen("singles.txt","a+");
  fwrite($file,$name,$gender,$age,$personality,$OS,$age_min,$age_max);
  fclose($file); 
  print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
```

If any other information is needed, I can try and help out!

Comment: make a string of these values and then pass into fwrite() function.

Comment: Change the fwrite to `fwrite($file,"$name,$gender,$age,$personality,$OS,$age_min,$age_max");`

Comment: Is your problem resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

Function fwrite expects you to pass the file pointer (in your case, $file) and the string you want to write. If you want a comma-separated list, then you should do it like this:

`fwrite($file,$name . "," . $gender . "," . $age . "," . $personality . "," . $OS . "," . $age_min . "," . $ag);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
  $personality = $_POST['personality'];
  $OS = $_POST['OS'];
  $age_min = $_POST['age_min'];
  $age_max = $_POST['age_max'];

   $variable_str = $name.",".$gender.",".$age.",".$personality.",".$os.",".$age_min.",".$age_max;

  $file = fopen("singles.txt","a+");
  fwrite($file,$variable_str);
  fclose($file); 
  print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
```

You should make a string of these values and then pass into fwrite() function. for more details about the fwrite() [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp) is here.